# Does dependency in testNg cause rerun?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

For example, I have the following methods and I run the whole test class.

```
public void previous() {
 .......
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods={"previous"})
    public void current() {
 .......
}
```

If that is the case, how many times will the previous methods be run?

Comment: What happened when **you** tried it?

Comment: I don't want to mess up the data

Answer (score 1):

Only one time. However, please remember dependsOnMethods mean

- If previous method result is PASSED, current method will run
- If previous method result is FAILED, current method will NOT run